# Using thrust to perform lookup on device

Tags: cuda, thrust

I want to use Thrust to make a lookup operation faster (using GPU). I have a relative small lookup table (122 elements) saved as array in a header file for that.
The idea is:

- *float4 *molecule_device* is the pointer to the array holding the key to look up (in 4th component)
- after the lookup I want to replace the key with additional information from the lookup table
- *int* colour_device* is where I want the looked up information to be stored
- a parameter (int) to determine what information/column is to be returned

There are three points in particular I'm struggling with:

1. The array are already malloced and populated on the device. To use the array with thrust I need to cast it to a thrust device pointer. Can I use this pointer in a thrust for each as begin iterator or do I have to take additional steps there?
2. What combination of zip iterator and tuples do I need to loop over the first array and store the data in both the molecule array (replace key) and the colour array?
3. How can I add the column integer to the function I defined for thrust?

Below is a basic version I'd like to get working (shortened at some places)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/for_each.h>
#include <thrust/tuple.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/transform_reduce.h>

#include <atomdata.cuh>
#include <reader.hpp>

template <typename T>
struct lookup
{
    __host__ __device__
        thrust::tuple<T, T>
        operator()(thrust::tuple<float4 &, int &> a) const
    {
        unsigned int symbol = (int)thrust::get<0>(a).w; // the key
        float x;
        uint y;
        findEntry(symbol, 1, &x, &y); // the 1 needs to be replaced by the column integer
        return thrust::make_tuple(x, y);
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    int numAtoms = 400;
    float4 *molecule;
    float4 *molecule_device;
    uint *colors_device;
    int column = 1;

    molecule = new float4[numAtoms];
    std::string filePath = ".../3i40.pdb";  // path shortend
    readFile(filePath, molecule, numAtoms); // this populates the molecule array; every datapoint is an atom with coordinates (x,y,z) and a radius (w)
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&(molecule_device), numAtoms * sizeof(float4)));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(molecule_device, molecule, numAtoms * sizeof(float4), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc((void **)&(colors_device), numAtoms * sizeof(uint)));

    thrust::device_ptr<float4> dev_molecule_ptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(molecule_device);
    thrust::device_ptr<int> dev_colour_ptr = thrust::device_pointer_cast(colour);
    auto start_zip = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(dev_molecule_ptr, dev_colour_ptr));

    thrust::for_each_n(start_zip, atom_count, lookup()); // here I'm totally lost
    
    return 0;
}
```

The header file with the lookup table:

```
#ifndef ATOMDATA_CUH
#define ATOMDATA_CUH

#ifndef ELEMENTS
#define ELEMENTS 112
#endif

typedef unsigned int uint;

struct entry
{
    uint symbol;

    float rSingleBonds1;
    float rSingleBonds2;
    float rVanDerWaals;

    uint cCorey;
    uint cKoltun;
    uint cJmol;
    uint cRasmolOld;
    uint cRasmolNew;
    uint cPubChem;
};

const entry pse[ELEMENTS] = {
#ifndef ATOMDATA_CUH
#define ATOMDATA_CUH

#include <string>

#ifndef ELEMENTS
#define ELEMENTS 112
#endif

typedef unsigned int uint;

struct entry
{
    uint symbol;

    float rSingleBonds1;
    float rSingleBonds2;
    float rVanDerWaals;

    uint cCorey;
    uint cKoltun;
    uint cJmol;
    uint cRasmolOld;
    uint cRasmolNew;
    uint cPubChem;
};

const entry pse[ELEMENTS] = {
    {2384, .31f, .32f, 1.2f, (uint)0xffffff, (uint)0xffffff, (uint)0xffffff, (uint)0xffffff, (uint)0xffffff, (uint)0x638c8c},
    {5324, .28f, .46f, 1.4f, (uint)0xffc0cb, (uint)0xffc0cb, (uint)0xd9ffff, (uint)0xffc0cb, (uint)0xffc0cb, (uint)0xd593a1},
    // ... remaining lines similar; cut for size purposes ...   
    {6219, .0f, 1.22f, .0f, (uint)0xffc0cb, (uint)0xffc0cb, (uint)0xffc0cb, (uint)0xffb6c1, (uint)0xffb6c1, (uint)0xffb6c1}};

__host__ __device__ void findEntry(uint symbol, uint case, float *radius_out, uint *color_out)
{
    uint n = 0;
    for (uint i = 0; i < ELEMENTS; i++)
    {
        if (symbol == pse[i].symbol)
        {
            *radius_out = pse[n].rVanDerWaals;
            int color;
            // ... some switch statements
            *color_out = color;
            break;
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

I searched online for similar thrust implementations/problems. Most use some combination of zip iterators and tuples to solve this (hence my code above). However I haven't found an implementation, that changes values in both the first (search) vector as well as the output vector.

The code above is minimal example. I didn't include the population of the array, as it's quite complex and not interesting (for testing any random floats do the trick).

I didn't compile the minimal example because my code setup isn't very flexible; likewise I don't expect any full coded answer and would be happy about any help about my approach.

Comment: A lookup does not magically get faster by using thrust

Comment: Use a struct of arays to store the pse elements insteadbof array of struct

Comment: @AbatorAbetor I have to move some other code parts to the GPU; therefor the lookup has to be done there as well. That's why I should gain a speedup (sry, didn't mention that). How would a struct of arrays change the handling of the lookup with thrust?

Comment: "To use the array with thrust I need to cast it to a thrust device pointer" You can use raw pointers with Thrust. You just need to be careful to pass the correct execution policies to the algorithms to avoid memory access violations. Without execution policy Thrust will assume raw pointers to point to host memory.

Comment: The main point of Thrust is to be able to write code that runs well on both CPU and GPU. By getting rid of Thrust for memory management and transfers as well as using `for_each` which is hardly an algorithm you basically have no good reason for using Thrust over a plain CUDA kernel. The only thing Thrust is still abstracting away for you is the concept of thread blocks. The resulting code is neither necessarily particularly fast nor readable.

Comment: Better than the current `for_each` would be a `transform` that takes `dev_molecule_ptr` for the input range and zipped `dev_molecule_ptr` and `dev_colour_ptr` as the output range.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to pass a parameter to the functor. This can be done by having a data member in the functor class `lookup` which is initialized with a constructor. Passing the parameter as a zipped `constant_iterator` is also possible and maybe more general but probably unneeded here.

Comment: For context to @AbatorAbetor's comments read about [memory coalescing](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#coalesced-access-to-global-memory) and [warp divergence](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#branching-and-divergence). The former is the main limiter of performance for bandwith bound algorithms like this and is one reason for zipping ranges of a PODs (SoA) instead of directly using ranges of structs (AoS). The second is the reason why your lookup scheme isn't ideal (`break` causing warp divergence).

Comment: this does sound like a lot of work to get it going with thrust. As far as I understood you, a kernel to do all that could be just as good. In that case I would just go with the kernel so spare me some trouble adapting.
About the divergence: So the break results in the compiler not being able to use prediction. Would it be better to run through the whole array instead?

Comment: On second thought: I'm planning to do some sorting after that lookup (sort by keys). Would the same argument apply? Should I do the whole thing (including memory management with thrust or do all kernels? The sorting seems quite complex with kernels only

Comment: For sorting you can use CUB directly which is used in the backend of Thrust.

Comment: "Would it be better to run through the whole array instead?" Not really, just be aware that the warp will basically take as long as the thread/lane that takes the most iterations. Coalescing is the bigger issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Never heard about CUB, but seems to be exactly what I need.